# How to send push to specific devicetoken on php function

Tags: php, ionic-framework, push, devicetoken

I'm Using Ionic Framework V1.
I've already get push notifications through Postman using 
and I've already save all devicetokens in my DB, but i'm stuck at getting any push for specific devices in php functions.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"tokens": ["DEV_DEVICE_TOKEN"],
"profile": "PROFILE_NAME",
"notification": {
    "message": "This is my demo push!"
}
```

Example:

```
public function confirmAction($request){
    $action = $this->find($request->idtblAction);
    $action->idtblStatus=1;
    if($action->save()){
   //I need to send notification in this part
        return Response::json(array('success'=>'true'));
    }else{
        return Response::json(array('success'=>'false'));
    }
}
```

Ionic io uses Bearer key and profileapp
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solve this without using php. I did it through my internal ionic app code.
Thank you to everybody!